# Connect facebook in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am new to Facebook connect.

So can any one tell me how to add facebook with our applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple things you need to do,

Get face book SDK from following link http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK

From here you will get all the information you are needed and you can add all the other informations to load sdk in your applications.

Answer (score 3):

> So can any one tell me how to add face book with our applications??

Facebook can. http://developers.facebook.com/